# Array of attributes for filtering elements

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I want to sort a set of films by several attributes, such as genre or format. The idea is that the user selects with checkbox elements the type of films he wants to appear on the screen. My question is, how could it be inserted several attributes, such as inserting several names like an array in order to filter them?

```
<div id="filters" class="filters">
  <strong>Format:&nbsp</strong>
    <input type="checkbox" name="format" value="Standard">Standard &nbsp&nbsp
    <input type="checkbox" name="format" value="3D">3D &nbsp&nbsp
    <input type="checkbox" name="format" value="Imax">Imax <br>  

  <strong>Genre:&nbsp</strong>
    <input type="checkbox" name="genre" value="comedy">Comedy &nbsp&nbsp
    <input type="checkbox" name="genre" value="drama">drama &nbsp&nbsp
    <input type="checkbox" name="genre" value="sciencefiction">Science fiction &nbsp&nbsp
    <input type="checkbox" name="genre" value="horror">Horror <br>

</div>
```

Comment: Can't help you if we don't know how you were planning for it to work. How about you show us some code that you tried to use to get your filtering effect - ie this array of attributes to filter and how to test each element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that movies are represented with array:

```
var movies = [
  {
    title: 'Avatar',
    format: '3D',
    genre: 'sciencefiction'
  },
  {
    title: 'Saw',
    format: 'Standard',
    genre: 'horror'
  }
];
```

You'll need to filter this array based on what checkboxes are checked. You can do this in an event listener:

```
// Some code skipped for brewity

$controls.on('change', function () {
    var formats = $formats.filter(':checked').map(getValue).get();
    var genres = $genres.filter(':checked').map(getValue).get();

    var filtered = movies.filter(function (e) {
        var formatMatch = formats.length === 0 || formats.indexOf(e.format) > -1;
        var genreMatch = genres.length === 0 || genres.indexOf(e.genre) > -1;

        return formatMatch && genreMatch;
    });

    render($output, filtered);
});
```

Full demo: http://jsfiddle.net/V4aW2/